# Upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10 failing under WSL

Tags: 19.10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, do-release-upgrade

I have a 19.04 installation running under Windows Subsystem for Linux. When I try to upgrade to 19.10, the following happens:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1554 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1329 kB]
Fetched 1331 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'eoan.tar.gz' against 'eoan.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'eoan.tar.gz'

Reading cache
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
lspci: Cannot find any working access method.

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97.5 kB]
Fetched 284 kB in 6s (45.8 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
=== Command detached from window (Wed Feb  5 12:39:40 2020) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Wed Feb  5 12:39:50 2020) ===
```

Apparently, the upgrade script wants to probe the PCI bus for some reason, which fails under WSL.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS. On https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/3489 I found an advice to remove snapd:

```
sudo apt remove --purge snapd
```

which solved the issue.